# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 17,Token in error = NOT ]

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8

This is weird kind error, i am working on a wp8 app when i am creating a local db using linq to sql its creating only for single datacontext if i add another table to datacontext or changes the name of datacontext its showing me the error what i paste in Title i m adding both of my codes here.
Thanks in advance

My Entity Class which is working fine if i use it alone in Datacontext class

```
  [Table]
  public class Employee
  {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int No { get; set; }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public string SchoolId { get; set; }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public string LogoUrl { get; set; }
  }
```

DataContext Class

```
    public class EmployeeDataContext : DataContext
    {
        public EmployeeDataContext(string ConnectionString)
            : base(ConnectionString)
        {
        }

        public Table<Employee> Employees
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Employee>();
            }
        }
    }

private const string Constr = @"isostore:/LclDb.sdf"; // Connection string
```

database creation using this code
its working fine till here but if i add another table to DataContext then its not creating database.

```
private const string Constr = @"isostore:/LclDb.sdf"; // Connection string
     using (EmployeeDataContext EmpDb = new EmployeeDataContext(Constr))
                    {
                        if (EmpDb.DatabaseExists() == false)
                        {
                            EmpDb.CreateDatabase();
                            MessageBox.Show("Created");
                        }
                    }
```

Another Entity which i am tring to add

```
   [Table]
   public class School_Table
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public string SchoolCode { get; set; }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public string SchoolLogoUrl { get; set; }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public string SchoolNameUrl { get; set; }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public string SchoolWebsiteUrl { get; set; }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public int LeaveStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you please post the entity which when added you get this error?

Comment: Just edit your post and add that code. Dont you see the edit option?

Comment: Error is not only for this entity, its binding me with that employee entity and employeedatacontext its throwing error in all other cases...

Comment: Dont you think you need to add `Table<School_Table>` to your `DbContext`? Also are there any more details from the exception which you share?

Comment: I shared the Code when its working fine, i added School_Table to datacontext and after adding it when i execute code its shows the error.
And there is nothing else its showing the same message again and again.... I was thinking can be it because of emulator but i reseted emulator as well but.....